# MacOS Launchd WatchPaths for notifications DB not running script

Tags: bash, macos, plist, launchd

I want to run a script every time there is a notification on MacOS. I setup launchd to watch the DB location:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
     <key>Label</key>
     <string>WatchNotifications</string>
     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
     <array>
          <string>/Users/***/Documents/***/myScript.sh</string>
     </array>
     <key>WatchPaths</key>
     <array>
           <string>/private/var/folders/***secret***/com.apple.notificationcenter/db2/</string>
     </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Doesn't run the script though. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:
Did you Terminal command `chmod +x ~/Documents/***/myScript.sh` ?

Secondly:
Did you know that apparently `db-wal` (which stores notifications' info) is *NOT* re-written when changed?
Therefore `WatchPaths` doesn't notice any change, unlike e.g. with TextEdit files that *ARE* re-written when saving changes; sadly `WatchPaths` only reports deleted or "added" files, quite like Folder Action Scripts do …

Comment: The only way I found so far is to monitor the file modified date every x seconds.

Comment: Yes, I suspect regular commands won't do, maybe ASobjC, but I just started to read into it. Btw: I do recommend BitBar (GitHub) for such things! … I use it to run an AS that displays the # of my Desktop like this: `[ 2 ]`. Its ease of use is phenomenal. Just put any script into its folder and its output is shown in your menu bar. By naming it "Name.5s.sh" it will automatically be run every 5 seconds! * * * * * Have a merry Christmas, I'm "off" a few days !